# TypeError: receipt.gasUsed.mul is not a function

Tags: ethers.js, hardhat

**Hardhat testing**

```
1) stakeEther
       should transfer ether and update balances correctly:
     TypeError: receipt.gasUsed.mul is not a function
      at Context.<anonymous> (test\Test.js:53:37)
      at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)
```

```
describe("stakeEther", function () {
  it("should transfer ether and update balances correctly", async function () {
    let contractBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(
      stakingContract.getAddress()
    );

    let signerBalance = await ethers.provider.getBalance(deployer.getAddress()); // Use 'address' property instead of 'getAddress()'
    const transferAmount = ethers.parseEther("2.0");

    const data = { value: transferAmount };
    const transaction = await stakingContract
      .connect(deployer)
      .stakeEther(30, data);

    const receipt = await transaction.wait();

    const gasUsed = receipt.gasUsed.mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice);

    // test the change in deployer ether balance
    expect(await deployer.getBalance()).to.equal(
      signerBalance.sub(transferAmount).sub(gasUsed)
    );

    // test the change in contract ether balance
    expect(
      await ethers.provider.getBalance(stakingContract.getAddress())
    ).to.equal(contractBalance.add(transferAmount));
  });
});
```

I am trying to calculate the gas cost through `transaction.wait()`.

I don't understand why this function is not working.

Hence I am using latest ethers and hardhat versions.

Please provide solutions.

Comment: You can try `const gasUsed = BigNumber.from(receipt.gasUsed).mul(receipt.effectiveGasPrice);`. See if the error changes at least

Answer (score 2):

## Things have changed in ethers v6 as compared to ethers v5.

In ethers version 5, we have to use these functions such as add() , mul(),div() etc , but in ethers version 6, javascript takes cares of all the things, you don't need to use these function inseted just use regulat + ,- ,* ,/

#### Replace the code where these functions have been used

```
//first change
const gasUsed = receipt.gasUsed * receipt.effectiveGasPrice ; 

//2nd change
    expect(await deployer.getBalance()).to.equal((
      signerBalance-transferAmount)-gasUsed
    );

    // test the change in contract ether balance
    expect(
      await ethers.provider.getBalance(stakingContract.getAddress())
    ).to.equal(contractBalance + transferAmount);
```

Answer (score 0):

It came to me while debugging receipt that u should make following changes :

```
const gasUsed = receipt.gasUsed * receipt.gasPrice;
```

Since, receipt provides gasPrice instead of effectiveGasPrice.
Also, gasPrice is of type BigInt.

read about BigInt :

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt